# Multiplying values in a matrix if criteria is met using an Excel formula, not VBA

Tags: excel

**Background**

I have a matrix and I'm working to determine costing without having to have a separate table to show the cost values per line item.  I would consider each value to consist of a 3x5 matrix, in this example, where the table/matrix shows an *Area* being worked in, the *Rate* for the line item, and the *Value* (values 0-29, 30 items).

The data is laid out as such:

```
Area    Rate   Value0    Value1
µ       A      1         6
µ       B      2         7
ö       C      3         8
ö       D      4         9
µ       E      5         10
```

I am trying to find the total for Value0 and Value1 for each Area, µ and ö, such that:

```
Value0,µ=If(Area(A)=µ,A*1,0)+...+If(Area(E)=µ,E*5,0)
Value1,µ=If(Area(A)=µ,A*6,0)+...+If(Area(E)=µ,E*10,0)

Value0,ö=If(Area(A)=ö,A*1,0)+...+If(Area(E)=ö,E*5,0)
Value1,ö=If(Area(A)=ö,A*6,0)+...+If(Area(E)=ö,E*10,0)
```

**Issue:**

I have gone through and attempted to lay out the the above if-statement based additions of the multiplied values in the matrix.  The example of A-E is small, but my actual set of data is roughly 200 lines.  I am hoping to find a way to go this without using VBA, but am a bit unfamiliar with how to use arrays to do this, or if it is possible to check a scenario before multiplying.

**Question:**

Is it possible to set-up an equation to multiply like an array in Excel, without having to use the set-up I gave in the background (shown below so you don't have to scroll up).

```
Value0,µ=If(Area(A)=µ,A*1,0)+...+If(Area(E)=µ,E*5,0)
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're looking for the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)

Comment: Using your provided sample data (and assuming that the A, B, C, etc for the Rates are actually numbers), the formula would look like this for Value0: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A6="µ"),B2:B6,C2:C6)`

Comment: @tigeravatar Thanks for that!  Forgot about that function completely.